# Freezing or melting Brine

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, ice, electrochemistry

In the freezing of [brine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brine), is it possible to do it at a rater or in such a way that the water only freezes or the ice is somehow isolated?

Or conversely is this possible in the melting of brine-ice?

Comment: What is a rater?

Comment: @KyleKanos: I believe OP means a *rate*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Hmm, that might be the case.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking if the concentration of the brine will change during the process of freezing? The answer is, yes, brine can freeze in such a way that the ice will contain a lower concentration of salt and the remaining brine will have a higher concentration. It is a major effect in the ice formation in the Arctic and Antarctic oceans: http://nsidc.org/cryosphere/seaice/characteristics/brine_salinity.html. I can't tell you the thermodynamics of it of the top of my head, though.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking into the desalination of water in the freezing or melting process.

Answer (score 1):

In thermodynamic equilibrium, the solidification process can be tracked using the phase diagram of water and salt.  One example (from wikipedia) is:

[image: H2O-NaCl]

It is fairly straightforward as a binary phase diagram.  Above 0C, adding NaCl to water results in complete dissolution until somewhere above 26.3 wt.%.  At that point, trying to stir more in will result in NaCl crystals on the bottom of you glass (and it is REALLY salty water).  You can also see the melting point depression of a eutectic, with 23.3 wt.% NaCl dropping the melting point to below -20C.

Now, if you have some salt in solution in water above 0C, what happens as you cool the mixture?  Eventually you hit the green line going from (0% NaCl, 0C) to (23.3 wt.% NaCl, -20C) - this is the boundary of a two phase regions.  Dropping below the line initiates a phase separation in the two phase region - ice in equilibrium with a brine solution with increasing NaCl content.  Continuing to cool keeps concentrating salt in the brine.

You might think you've just purified the water, but that isn't really true - this isn't a particularly good phase diagram, since there is some solubility of NaCl in ice that is not shown here (entropy demands there be some solubility even if it is really low).  But, the ice that initially forms does have less NaCl in it than the original mixture, so you could take that, melt it, and refreeze.  This type of process is used extensively for purifying materials, often called zone melt refining.  Once upon a time you could obtain float-zone refined silicon (it doesn't scale up beyond 6" wafers, so you can't anymore). However, you cannot get below the intrinsic solid solubility of the impurity in the solid.